# Moving all files in sub directories into a main directory

Tags: linux, mv

I have a directory called "public" that contains a thousand of subdirectories
eg:

```
public/63a/e9b/79a/file.pdf 
public/64a/2cd/184/other_file.pdf
...
```

My aim is to move all the files contained in those subdirectories into the main  directory (ie: public).
I guess I need a recursive function to do that.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool to do so is already part of the standard Linux environment:

```
find public -type f -exec mv {} public/ \;
```

Explanation:

We want to `find` files but not diectories (`-type f`) in `public`and its substructure and on each file found execute (`-exec`) a command, which is to move it (represented by `{}`) to public.

The escaped semicolon just marks the end of the `-exec` sequence.